# How to automatically align the edges of features to other features from an other fetaure class?

Tags: arcmap, alignment, borders, arcgis-10.8

I have two feature classes containing polygons. One (lets call it `A`) covers the whole area of interest without any gap or overlap. The other (`B`) has polygons scattered over the area. The features of `B` roughly share the same edges/borders as `A`, but not exactly. I would like to align the polygon edges of `B` to the edges of `A` within a given tolerance, and since I have thousands of this, I would like to do it automatically.
What I have tried is `Integrate` in ArcMap 10.8.

On the attached image the black border is `A`, the blue patch is the original `B`, and the red dashed line is the new, integrated `B`. As you can see it made a pretty good job on the bottom edges, but for some reason touched the other vertices as well, even if they were way out of the tolerance level.
[image]
In the integrate tool I set the rank of `A` higher, but it did not help.
Is there any other tool (apart from the manual Align to Shape and Align to Edge tools), which can do this job for me?
As mentioned, I am using Arcmap 10.8, but I also have access to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Did you try Snap? You can first Densify your polygon edges which may yield a good result.

Comment: I I did try, and I know it works, but it basically does the same as Align to Edge tool, plus I can only do it manually, and I would need something automated.

Comment: Not an ArcGIS solution, but I tried the `snap geometries to layer` tool of QGIS and it works pretty well!

Comment: I meant https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm, which requires a Standard or Advanced licence and does all in an automatic fashion. I think `snap geometries to layer` and the `snap tool` works in the same way.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you! I have no idea how I missed this tool...

Comment: OK then, I am converting my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Snap tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm), which requires a Standard or Advanced licence and does all in an automatic fashion. I think `snap geometries to layer` of QGIS and this tool works in the same way. Applying [Densify tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) to your feature edges prior to snap may give you a better result.